# How to remove same items in a list in fewest sentence?

Tags: python

```
A = [1,2,2,2,3]
cleaned_A = [1,2,3]
```

I know the remove() method or turned list A into set. 
I am wondering if there is a quicker way to do so without changing the data structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "without changing the data structure"? What constitutes "changing the data structure", and why do you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Use set to make values unique:

```
cleaned_A = list(set(A))
```

Comment: `I know the remove() method or turned list A into set` - from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into a set and then back into a list to remove duplicates. Try this:

```
>>> A = [1,2,2,2,3]
>>> A = list(set(A))
>>> A
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `I know the remove() method or turned list A into set` - from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to `set` and then back to `list` this way:

```
cleaned_A = list(set(A))
```

Comment: `I know the remove() method or turned list A into set` - from the question.

Comment: I think this might be the best way..

Answer (score 1):

Without sets

```
>>> list({}.fromkeys(A))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution has to be at least `O(N)` since you have to check all the items in the list at least once.

So, lets say A = [1,2,2,2,3]

```
cleaned_A = set()
for i in A:
    cleaned_A.add(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
>>> A = [1,2,2,2,3]
>>> reduce(lambda seen, item: seen + [item] if item not in seen else seen, A, [])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be my first choice, but you could list.index and list.pop to remove items that already exist earlier in the list. That way you keep the original structure.

```
A = [1,2,2,2,3]
i = len(A) - 1
while i >= 0:
    if A.index(A[i]) != i:
        A.pop(i)
    i -= 1
```

However, modifying a list in place multiple times is more expensive that building up a fresh list from scratch once. This method is already O(N^2).

I recommend just using the list(set(A)) method unless you have a particular use case that forbids it.